# Javascript & Combobox - Send the value of an item focused

Tags: javascript, combobox

I have a combobox with some values :

```
<select id="combo" name="my_combo" size="0" onchange="myFunction(this.getFocusedValue)"> 
    <option value="1">1 Mese</option>
    <option value="2">2 Mesi</option>
    <option value="3">3 Mesi</option>
    <option value="4">4 Mesi</option>
</select>
```

I want to translate that `this.getFocusedValue` on a real JavaScript code :)

How can I do this? Would be nice if this works on all browser (else i can use Jquery).

Thanks

**SOLUTION**

```
<select id="combo" name="my_combo" size="0" onchange="changeArticle(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
```

Comment: That isn't a combobox. A combobox is a combination (hence the name) of a drop down menu and a textbox. A select element generates a drop down menu (or a list box) but no textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.selectedIndex;`

**Edit:**

```
index = this.selectedIndex;
return this.options[index].value;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yeah this could work. But this doesnt return the "value". It just return the index. If the value (for example) was `4-3-2-1` (and not `1-2-3-4`) and i select the 4° option, it returns `3` and not `1`. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Nice. Added the solution. Hope this works on each browser :) thanks man

Comment: Yeah, it'll work in all browsers going back several years. I remember this technique from IE5.0. I'm a little rusty on it now because I mostly use jQuery.

Comment: Uhm yeah. But in fact, how Can you do this by JQuery?

Comment: `$('#myselect').change(function () { $(this).val(); });`